How to fix checkpoint requests problems?
On PostgreSQL v15 every morning at 5:15 AM starts heavy inserts in our database and finishes around 7:00 AM. I try to see if there are some parameters that can be tuned like checkpoints.
I have written a script that executes the following SQL: SELECT checkpoints_timed, checkpoints_req FROM pg_stat_bgwriter to get "checkpoints timed" vs. "checkpoints requested". Or in other words do "checkpoints requested" appears at morning heavy inserts.
I have set log_checkpoints=onpostgresql.conf parameter checkpoints info to be written in database server log file. I see the following related to checkpoints:
2024-09-09 05:22:34 LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-09-09 05:33:37 LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 779881 buffers (8.9%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 483 removed, 664 recycled; write=652.802 s, sync=0.165 s, total=662.212 s; sync files=170, longest=0.059 s, average=0.001 s; distance=12326973 kB, estimate=12326973 kB

2024-09-09 05:34:27 LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal
2024-09-09 05:48:27 LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 1818364 buffers (20.7%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1009 recycled; write=837.323 s, sync=0.097 s, total=839.269 s; sync files=175, longest=0.024 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16533226 kB, estimate=16533226 kB

2024-09-09 05:50:24 LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal
2024-09-09 06:06:02 LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 1302347 buffers (14.8%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1010 recycled; write=938.102 s, sync=0.068 s, total=938.629 s; sync files=301, longest=0.011 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16547328 kB, estimate=16547328 kB

2024-09-09 06:08:20 LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal
2024-09-09 06:35:20 LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 1015915 buffers (11.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 880 recycled; write=1619.413 s, sync=0.038 s, total=1619.779 s; sync files=488, longest=0.020 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16548651 kB, estimate=16548651 kB

2024-09-09 06:38:20 LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-09-09 07:05:20 LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 320834 buffers (3.7%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 376 recycled; write=1619.469 s, sync=0.004 s, total=1619.906 s; sync files=755, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=13792920 kB, estimate=16273078 kB


Whole day and night I see checkpoint starting: time events (just like in first line). I assume those are checkpoints timed events.  Exception is at the time: 5:34, 5:50 and 6:08 (see above log) where checkpoint starting: wal appears three times in sequence. I assume those are checkpoint requested event. According to theory those events slow down the database performance and should be avoided.
If we look at line 4, there is:

1818364 buffers. If multiplied by 8192 (block_size) and divided by 67 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 (shared_buffers) and we get 20.7%
20.7% is the percentage of memory buffers changed (dirty blocks from checkpoint starting point to checkpoint completed events) that are requested to be saved by checkpoint to $PGDATA/base/"database"/ Data Files.
0 WAL file(s) added: There was no need to add additional WAL files, because all are already added (according to max_wal_size parameter)
1009 recycled - number of old WAL files renamed and reused
write=837.323 s - is 13 min and 57 seconds - time how long checkpoint needed to complete (also the time from "checkpoint starting: wal" to "checkpoint complete")
sync=0.097 s - probably some disk fsync or similar (negligible in our case, because of very small number)
total=839.269 s - probably "write + sync + 'something'"
sync files=175 - is number of Data Files written by checkpoint in $PGDATA/base/"database"/ directory from checkpoint "start" to "complete".
longest=0.024 s - maximal time for individual Data File to be written
average=0.001 s - average time for Data File to be written

Now there are two parameters that I don't understand the meaning:

distance=16533226 kB - 15.7 GB
estimate=16533226 kB - 15.7 GB

QUESTIONS:

What does distance/estimate means?
Why is in my case checkpoint request fired?
Is increasing max_wal_size recommended? If yes, how to calculate new parameter size?
Is some other parameter recommended like decrease checkpoint_completion_target to e.g. 0.8?

PostgreSQL instance settings:
 shared_buffers: 67GB
 wal_buffers:    32MB
 full_page_writes: on
 max_wal_size:   30GB
 checkpoint_timeout: 30min
 checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
 min_wal_size: 512MB
 block_size: 8192
 wal_segment_siz: 16MB

Regards

"What is in my case checkpoint request fired?"  I don't understand what you are asking.  Did you mean to ask 'why' instead of 'what'?  Can you rephrase this somehow?  Anyway, you seem to be digging into trivialities, rather than trying to fix an actual problem.

Increate max_wal_size to get fewer checkpoints.

As well as increasing max_wal_size you should also look at increasing the checkpoint_timeout also!

@jjanes, it was typo, fixed. You are right, I am digging maybe too deep... because I don't understand why "checkpoint request" was triggered.
@Laurenz, is there some recipe how much should max_wal_size be increased? Like just double the size?
@Vérace, I was looking at max_wal_sizie and checkpoint_timeout but the side effect may be increasing crash recovery time if (when) it happens. That is why I am trying to be more careful.

The distance and estimate numbers are not described in the documentation, and the description in the source code are not very good.  They appear to roughly correspond to "how much WAL was generated during the checkpoint which just finished" and "how much WAL is likely to be generated during the next checkpoint".  I think they are used to figure out how much WAL to recycle ahead (rather than delete) for future use, as well as how soon and how fast the next checkpoint needs to be run in order to complete "on target".
I would expect those values to be closer to max_wal_size (30GB) than they are, and I don't have a good explanation for why they are not.  But it doesn't matter.  If the checkpoints were being requested every 10 seconds, that is likely a problem.  But every 15 minutes (rather than the 30 minute timeout value) is not likely to be a problem.  You could try doubling or tripling max_wal_size to get rid of the "checkpoint starting: wal" records by converting to 'time' instead, but this is unlikely to improve performance by any meaningful amount.
If you have a performance problem, you should tackle it more directly, for example by sampling the insert operations in pg_stat_activity and seeing what the common wait_event are, or by inspecting the system with top to see where the time is going.
